# Postgresql 9.2 error with group by which doesn't appear in postgresql 12

Tags: group-by, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-12

I have a postgresql function with 'GROUP BY' which works fine on my local server (postgresql version is 12.6) but gets the famous error 'column "f.fa_docnum" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function' on the web server, which runs postgresql 9.2.24. I'm completely confused about that. The documentation of the 2 versions are exactly the same for the GROUP BY clause.

Here is the function (a bit simpler than the original one, but it gets the same results) :

```
SELECT 
            f.fa_docnum,
            f.fa_date, 
            sum(l.lj_credit), 
            sum(l.lj_debit)
            FROM livrejournal l, document d, facture_achat f
            WHERE d.doc_id = l.lj_docid 
            AND d.doc_fa_docnum = f.fa_docnum
            AND f.fa_fournisseur = 59               
            GROUP BY (f.fa_docnum, f.fa_date);
```

On the production site with 9.2 version, I get no error if I delete 'f.fa_date' column in the GROUP BY clause, while on the local dev site with 12.6 (and formerly lower versions) I get no error in any case.
If anybody has an idea about this strange behavior, and maybe some tip or workaround, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You are only grouping by a **single** column due to the parentheses around the columns. The expression `(f.fa_docnum, f.fa_date)` is a **single** column with an anonymous record type that contains two fields.

It seems that Postgres 9.2 can't detect that one of the fields of the record expression is the primary key of the table and thus throws the error. While Postgres 12 *can* detect that one of the record's fields is the primary key column of the table.

The solution is to remove the parentheses around the columns. They server no purpose to begin with and are actually an error in your case.

Comment: Yes ! Your answer is perfect, thanks a lot. Unfortunately my reputation is still too low to allow me to upvote it. And for 9.2 version, I know it is obsolete but my host works with Cpanel which hasn't updated Postgresql nor phpPgAdmin, in spite of requests from (probably not so many) users.